# mysql IFNULL INSERT huge setback?

Tags: mysql, sql, ifnull

I am having a bit of a problem with some mysql. I will try to give a much background as I can. This is the situation, I had created an availability for my parent's plant nursery and stored the plant information in mysql, I did a terrible job the first time and now I am redoing it with the new knowledge I have gained in the mean time.

Background of the problem, I had 2 tables in the old database one being called `Gallery` with the following fields:

(`id`, `Plant_id_1`, `Plant_id_2`, `Plant_id_3`, `Plant_id_4`, `Plant_id_5`, `Image1`, `Image1_Copyright`, `Image2`, `Image2_Copyright`, `Scientific`, `Common`, `Category`, `Height`, `Spread`, `Exposure`, `Zone`, `Descp`).

The `Plant_id_1...` fields would be the `id` of the second table which is called `Availability` with the following fields:

(`id`, `name`, `size`, `description`, `available`, `upcomming`, `price`)

So as you can see I knew nothing about datases(still might not) but on to the new structure for the table, again 2 tables the first being called `plants` with the following fields:

(`id`, `scientific_name`, `common_name`, `category`, `height`, `spread`, `exposure`, `usda`, `description`, `image1_url`, `image1_copyright`, `image2_url`, `image2_copyright`)

The second being called `current` with the following fields:

(`id`, `plant_id`, `size`, `available`, `upcoming`, `price`, `description`)

The `plant_id` will be the id of the corresponding plant in the `plant` table.

Now on to the problem. I need to get the data from the old table and put it into the new table. I have all the plants from gallery in the new `plant` table no issue there. But now to get the `Availability` into the `Current` table.

This is an example from the export of the `Availability` (I took the top 3):

```
INSERT INTO `Availability` (`id`, `name`, `size`, `description`,`available`, `upcomming`, `price`) VALUES(91, 'Acer P.''Shishigashira''', ' #5', '30-36"', 27, 0, 36.00); 

INSERT INTO `Availability` (`id`, `name`, `size`, `description`, `available`,`upcomming`, `price`) VALUES(697, 'Arbutus U. ''Compacta''', ' #5','', 0, 0, 16.20); 

INSERT INTO `Availability` (`id`, `name`, `size`, `description`, `available`, `upcomming`, `price`) VALUES(90, 'Acer P.''Shigitatsusawa''', '#15', '', 0, 0, 65.00);
```

I need to get the `plant_id` from the plant table and put that into a insert statement, which I believe I have with the following:

```
INSERT INTO `current` (`plant_id`, `size`,`description`, `available`, `upcoming`, `price`) VALUES(
(SELECT  `id` 
FROM  `plants` 
WHERE  `scientific_name` 
REGEXP  'Acer P.+ ''Shishigashira'''),  ' #5', '30-36"', 27, 0, 36.00);
```

But now I have a new problem what if there is no plant in the `plant` table to match, So i need a ifnull in there. to create the plant with the scientific name and the rest null. well I am new to SQL so this is what I have and its not working:

```
INSERT INTO `current` (`plant_id`, `size`,`description`, `available`, `upcoming`, `price`) VALUES(
(IFNULL( SELECT IFNULL( (SELECT `id` 
FROM  `plants` 
WHERE  `scientific_name` 
REGEXP  'Chamaecyparis O.+ Nana'),( 
INSERT INTO  `plants` (`scientific_name`)
VALUES (Chamaecyparis O. 'Nana'))))),  ' #1', '', 0, 0, 9.25);
```

As you can see Its very complicated if you think you are up to the challenge of helping me i would beyond greatly appreciated. If no one can help me I will have to manually reenter all the data into the `current` table.

Comment: Do the id's you have in your new plant table match the ids in the old gallery table? I'm a bit lost as to why you think you have to search based on the scientific name and how that could ever be null since you stated that you copied all differents plants over. How can there suddenly be unknown plants then?

Comment: I wish, The reason it will return null is not all the plants in the availability are in the gallery. So what I was trying to do is create those missing plants in the plant gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work towards a select that returns the data you need to insert into your new table. Once 
you have that you can simply wrap that into a INSERT INTO - SELECT contruction. That way you don't have to export and do individual inserts. You can simply copy the whole set over in one go.

If you make sure that when you copy plants from the gallery into the plants table the id's stay intact I expect a select like this should return the rows you want to insert:

```
SELECT 
   Gallery.id as plant_id, 
   Availability.size, 
   Availability.available, 
   Availability.upcoming, 
   Availability.price,
   Availability.description
FROM Gallery 
INNER JOIN Availability
ON Gallery.Plant_id1 = Availability.id
```

Then you can do the same thing 5 times where you change the

```
ON Gallery.Plant_id1 = Availability.id
```

to (one by one)

```
ON Gallery.Plant_id2 = Availability.id
ON Gallery.Plant_id3 = Availability.id
ON Gallery.Plant_id4 = Availability.id
ON Gallery.Plant_id5 = Availability.id
```

Or you put all of them together in one huge sql statement with a UNION ALL between each select

Comment: Tried what you suggested and i received this error, I guess i get what your getting at but the IDs are not the same from 'gallery' to 'plant' table.
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON Gallery.Plant_id2 = Availability.id
ON Gallery.Plant_id3 = Availability.id
ON' at line 11

Comment: Ok i see so i ran what you gave me had to change. ON Gallery.Plant_id1 = Availability.id to ON Gallery.Plant_id_1 = Availability.id. Note the underscore after plant_id. I see what you are suggesting it returned as you would expect but like i said the ids dont stay the same. Thanks now i have another path to go off. Ill do some more reserch.

Comment: So thanks to you I have my problem fixed. I did excally what you told me. I reimported the plants database with the original ids and then ran the command above to get the data i needed i then exported that as a csv and imported it into the current table. Thank you very much. I have spent 3 days on it now.